# How to execute script before the job starts?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to execute my shell script before the job starts? We are using the jenkins pipeline, but it is already late when Jenkins is processing this script - we are dealing with unknown problem with keychain and git, but we are using global libraries as well, that need to be downloaded from git before the pipeline script is executed.

Therefore we need to delete the items which are causing the problems from keychain BEFORE it downloads the global library for the job. Is there anything like this available in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), you can control which stage is executed. 
see below example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('before job starts') {
            steps {
                sh 'your_scripts.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('the job') {
            steps {
                sh 'run_job.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'I will always run!'
        }
    }
}
```